# Wrong arguments inside function (oracle)

Tags: oracle, function, varchar

I have basic function:

```
create or replace function t_owner(tname in varchar2, oname out varchar2)
return varchar2
is
begin
  select owner into oname from table where table_name = 'tname';
  return oname;
end;

select t_owner('table_test') from dual;
```

When I call it I'm getting this:

ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'T_OWNER'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions shouldn't have OUT parameters; they *return* that value anyway. So:

```
create or replace function t_owner(tname in varchar2)
  return varchar2  
is
  oname table.owner%type;       --> declare a local variable which will be returned
begin
  select owner into oname from table where table_name = tname;
  return oname;
end;
```

---

If you want to use `OUT` parameter, switch to a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure t_owner(tname in varchar2, oname out varchar2)
is
begin
  select owner into oname from table where table_name = tname;
end;
```

You'd call it as

```
declare
  l_out table.owner%type;
begin
  t_owner('table_test', l_out);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_out);
end;
```

Comment: please correct to table_name = tname; then is working OK, thanks for help

Comment: Bah! Of course, I copy/pasted your code and didn't notice that it was wrong. Fixed. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

`oname` should be a local variable, not an output parameter and `tname` should not be referenced as a string but an input parameter.

```
create or replace function t_owner(tname in varchar2)
return varchar2
is
    oname table.owner%type;
begin
    select owner into oname 
    from table 
    where table_name = tname;

    return oname;
end;

select t_owner('table_test') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

*a function is a subprogram that returns a single value, it implicitly returns only one out value, and so, no need to define as an argument, already pointed out by using `return` keyword. As a result you need to get rid of the second argument and convert it to a local variable :*

```
create or replace function t_owner( tname mytable.table_name%type )
 return mytable.owner%type
is
  oname mytable.owner%type;
begin
  select owner into oname from mytable where table_name = tname;
  return oname;
end;
```

Moreover

- remove quotes around variable `tname` in the select statement, otherwise existence of the argument would have no sense. Because wouldn't be used.
- define variables explicitly as `<table_name>.<column_name>%type` to emphasize for what they're defined, and against a probability may occur for the related table's data type or length.
- as being a reserved keyword, I replaced `table` with `mytable`.